# Is 'Got asleep' correct phrase?

Tags: tenses

Sentence example: I got asleep.

PS: I know `fell asleep` is more commonly accepted.

Comment: *I got to sleep* sounds nearly the same as *I got asleep* (and the answers below discuss what this means). Did you possibly mishear somebody?

Comment: Also, ***I gotta sleep***  (I’ve got to sleep)

Comment: I finally got asleep, and the my wife started snoring and woke me up.

Answer (score 1):

"Fall asleep" suggests it simply happened, perhaps unintentionally e.g. "Accidents are caused by people falling asleep whilst driving".

However "to fall asleep" is also used where it was a simple and straightforward process e.g. "I went to bed and quickly fell asleep".

"Getting to sleep" is more often used where there was some sort of impediment e.g "There was so much noise from the people next door that I couldn't get to sleep".

Or: "I eventually got to sleep about 3.00am".

Or it could be used to explain that sleep came more easily than might have been expected e.g. "I had no trouble getting to sleep".

**Your proposed expression "got asleep" is not often used - where "got" is employed, it is usually "got to sleep"**.

In all of the above I speak of British use. Different idiomatic rules may apply elsewhere.

Comment: For the record, I think everything you said applies to AmE as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not idiomatic. "To get" is a pro-verb. A pro-verb substitutes for a more precise verb. (This is like a pronoun - a word that substitutes for a noun.)

In your example, "get" has no clear meaning, and so the sentence is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not correct. You can say " I fell asleep". 
If you want to express you had difficulty falling asleep for some reason (insomnia, noisy surroundings...), you might say "I managed to fall asleep".
If you are determined to use an expression with "get", you can say "I got to sleep", but it implies some difficulty, as in this example: "It was very noisy, but I eventually got to sleep about three in the morning".